# Line detection in specific direction python

Tags: python, image

I have the following colored image

[image: Power chronogram]

I'm trying to extract the oblique parallel lines. These lines being oriented in the same direction.

I first tried to do a convolution with a tilted Sobel kernel :

```
from scipy import ndimage   
A = misc.imread('chronogram.png')    
kernel = np.array([[-2,-1,0],[-1,0,1],[0,1,2]])
im_conv = ndimage.convolve(rip_log, side_lobes_kernel)
```

[image: convolution result]

I also tried Canny filter and Hough transform but the lines are not distinguishable enough on the image. Or I didn't use the right parameters.

```
from skimage.transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks,
                           probabilistic_hough_line)
from skimage.feature import canny
edges = canny(rip_log, sigma=3)
theta = np.arange(np.pi/6,np.pi/3, 0.01) # To look for the right angle
hough = hough_line(rip_log,theta)
```

I think that using a convolution kernel could be the right way to go, but having few experience in the image processing, I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a 2-D convolution with your desired streak. Using a tiny kernel (3x3 in your example) will be highly susceptible to noise. Instead, make it as wide as the signal, which appears to be the full width of the image.

As for how, you could use SciPy:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate a kernel to convolve with
line = np.rot90(np.eye(50))
plt.imshow(line)
```

[image]

```
# generate some synthetic data
noisy = np.random.random((200, 50)) * 0.3
for i in range(30):
    x = random.randrange(150)
    noisy[x:x+50,:] += line
plt.imshow(noisy)
```

[image]

```
# convolve the two
result = signal.convolve2d(noisy, line, mode='valid')
plt.plot(result)
```

[image]

Because the kernel width matched the data, and I used the "valid" range for convolution, the output is 1-dimensional (or has only one dimension of size other than 1)